# ios swift: lag when changing navigationbar title font across different VCs

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

There is some lag when switching navbar title fonts between VCs, any help appreciated.

On my mainVC I set the navbar title font in viewDidLoad as:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Billabong", size: 27)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

And, to switch back to the normal font on the other following VCs, I change the font back to normal on the mainVC viewWillDisappear as:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Up to here everything is fine, and the newVC shows the original font just fine, but when going back to the mainVC the font change has some lag. The way I'm doing it is by using the viewWillDisappear from the newVC displayed, however when it returns to the mainVC it shows half the title with the new font followed by ... and after some short lag it displays the rest of the title (eg "CoolTi..." and then "CoolTitle").

I've tried using viewWillAppear on the mainVC and same thing happens, also tried viewDidAppear on the mainVC and the lag on font change is even worse. Not sure how to switch back to other font without the lag, any ideas? Thanks

[SOLVED] Thanks @warrenm: 
using `navigationItem.titleView` for the mainVC title instead and no lag when switching fonts between VCs
code:

```
let coolTitle = UILabel()
coolTitle.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "coolTitle", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Billabong", size: 27)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
coolTitle.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = coolTitle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels like a UIKit bug for the following reason: if the title of the pushed view controller is wider than the title of the main view controller, it seems to work. Only when the secondary VC's title is narrower does the main VC's title get truncated during the transition.

There are a lot of possible workarounds for this, but I would recommend explicitly setting the `titleView` property of each VC's navigation item to an appropriately configured `UILabel` with an attributed string. In this case, you'd leave the `title` property of the navigation items empty. You might want to then configure the `backBarButtonItem` of each navigation item with an appropriate title (since otherwise your back buttons will have the generic title "Back").

Comment: Hey Warren! I can't make the titleView display anything :( posted by mistake, typing more info ...

Comment: needed to use `sizeToFit()` on the `UILabel` and it finally displayed, works like  a charm! and no lag when switching fonts between VCs. Thanks <3